# jQuery toggleClass - highlight one link at a time?

Tags: jquery, toggle, highlight

I have a list of links on a page, when the user clicks a link I would like it to become highlighted and at the same time I want the remaining links to become unhighlighted. The demo half way down at  http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ does exactly what I want however it allows you to highlight many links at once. Could anyone advise what I would need to tweak to get this to work? Many thanks.

Comment: Check this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057191/toggleclass-and-remove-class-from-all-other-elements

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest using something like:

```
$('a').click(
function(e){
    e.preventDefault; // don't follow the link
    $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).addClass('highlight')
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pLdQ3/1/).

`e.preventDefault;` stops the browser following the link. You may, or may not, wish to remove this line.

`$('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');` selects all elements of `class`-name 'highlight' and *removes* that `class`, so that only *one* link can have that class at any one time.

`$(this).addClass('highlight');` simply adds the class-name 'highlight' to the `this` element (the `a` in this example).

---

References:

- [`e.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).

Comment: No joy with your code at my end, but JS Fiddle looks useful - many thanks for sharing this so quickly.

Comment: I did have a typo in the first version of this code (I forgot to close the the string `$('a)`, which I amended subsequently). Does it work on JS Fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

In the above demo, you could remove the highlight class on all elements, and then call toggle on the clicked element:

```
 $("p").click(function () {
      $("p").removeClass("highlight");
      $(this).addClass("highlight");
    });
```

Comment: You should replace `toggleClass` with `addClass` since in your example the class is never present for it to be toggled off. The functionality will be the same, but you're removing an extra check

Comment: Lucian this works perfectly, thank you so much. JohnP thanks for your suggestion as well, I'll amend the code based on your advice. Thanks again for helping out so promptly guys this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Here is jquery.

```
$('a').click(
 function(){
  $('a').removeClass('highlight');
  $(this).addClass('highlight'); 
});
```

Comment: It's the same answer as Lucian's!

Answer (score -2):

I used the following solution for a nav tree I had with ~200 links. It uses a global var to hold the selector of the previous nav selection, which get's cleared when the user moves to another link :

```
var oldSelector = $();  // global var

$('a').on(click, 
function(){
    oldSelector.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    oldSelector = currentSelector;
});


// css
.selected {
background-color: lightblue;
}
```

I don't think there is much performance difference with this method as compared to what @David Thomas provided, but it's another way of doing the same thing.