# By clicking on different elements with the same css class, add css class to one of them but remove it from the others using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to add the text of specific `div` elements inside a textarea every time i click on each of those `divs` and style the one is active using jQuery:

Here is my code:

```js
$('.msg-item-row').each(function() {
$(this).click(function(){
$(this).addClass('selected-msg');
var msgtextslot = $(this).text();
$('#message').val(msgtextslot);

//alert (msgtextslot);
});
});
```

```css
.msg-item-row {
  background:#f3f5f8;
  color:#383838;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
  font-size:0.8rem;
}


#message {
width:90%;
padding:10px;
}

.selected-msg {
background:red;
color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="list-msg-wrapper">
<div class="msg-item-row"> Hi, i have some questions about this product. </div>
<div class="msg-item-row"> What is the most favorited color in the world? </div>
<div class="msg-item-row"> Bla bla bla bla bla</div>
</div>

<textarea id="message" name="message" rows="3" placeholder="Enter your message..."></textarea>
```

The code works pretty fine and i am able to style each div when i click it by adding the class ".selected-msg".
My problem is that i dont know how i can remove the class from the other two unselected divs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [toggleClass and remove class from all other elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057191/toggleclass-and-remove-class-from-all-other-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `removeClass` to remove the class from all buttons, then add the class to the one desired button:

```js
$('.msg-item-row').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function(){
    $('.msg-item-row').removeClass('selected-msg');
    $(this).addClass('selected-msg');
    var msgtextslot = $(this).text();
    $('#message').val(msgtextslot);
  });
});
```

```css
.msg-item-row {
  background:#f3f5f8;
  color:#383838;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
  font-size:0.8rem;
}


#message {
width:90%;
padding:10px;
}

.selected-msg {
background:red;
color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="list-msg-wrapper">
<div class="msg-item-row"> Hi, i have some questions about this product. </div>
<div class="msg-item-row"> What is the most favorited color in the world? </div>
<div class="msg-item-row"> Bla bla bla bla bla</div>
</div>

<textarea id="message" name="message" rows="3" placeholder="Enter your message..."></textarea>
```